# different command to create a remote repo in Git

Tags: git, git-remote

What are differences between these commands in Git (VCS tool) :

```
$ git init --bare
$ git init --bare --shared
$ git init --bare --shared=group
```

Would you please explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

```
   --shared[=(false|true|umask|group|all|world|everybody|0xxx)]
       Specify that the git repository is to be shared amongst several users. This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository. When
       specified, the config variable "core.sharedRepository" is set so that files and directories under $GIT_DIR are created with the requested permissions. When
       not specified, git will use permissions reported by umask(2).
```

What exactly are you puzzled about?

Comment: I use 'man git' command in terminal but haven't seen such lines ! where did you get them from?

Comment: Or, `git init --help` (you can use `--help` with any Git command)